# Add Send With Docusign in Custom lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, docusign

I am using Docusign V7.0+ in Salesforce. I want to redirect to the docusign page through lightning component while clicking on the button. Below is the javascript which I need to use that in lightning component.

```
 {!URLFOR('/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope', null, [
SourceID = PPME_PreEmployment__c.Id

]
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to redirect to URL is by using `e.force:navigateToURL` event in lightning controller.
Below is the code snippet.

Component:

```
<lightning:button label="DocuSign" onlick="{!c.gotoURL}" />
```

Lightning Controller JS:

```
({
    gotoURL : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.gotoURL(component);
    }
})
```

Lightning Helper JS:

```
({
        gotoURL : function (component) {
            var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
            urlEvent.setParams({
              "url": "/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?SourceID = "+PPME_PreEmployment__c.Id
            });
            urlEvent.fire();
        }
})
```

Comment: We have tried with your above suggestion. But its show the below message "**The link you followed isn’t valid. This page requires a CSRF confirmation token. Report this error to your Salesforce administrator.**"